# How to apply python loop on a series of files?

Tags: python, for-loop

I would like to run this command line on a series of files (file0 to file53):

```
./initram-v5.sh -f file0.gro -o file0_aa.gro -to amber -p topol.top
```

I'm trying to automatize the process by using a for loop in python rather than applying this command line on each of the 54 files that I have but I can't succeed.

Comment: You can use bash for loops to do this. Why use python?

Comment: Yeah you could do `for i in $(seq 53); do echo ./initram-v5.sh -f "file${i}.gro" -o "file${i}_aa.gro" -to amber -p topol.top; done`

Comment: Thank you for your help and suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run commands from python like this:

```
import os

cmd = "./initram-v5.sh -f file0.gro -o file0_aa.gro -to amber -p topol.top"
os.system(cmd)
```

Just remember that when using os.system you are running the command in the file directory of the file that has this code in it. You should be able to loop this(Note: os.system is a function, so anything after this block won't be executed until the function is finished)
Here is some modified code for you:

```
import os

fileNum = 0
numFiles = 53
while fileNum < numFiles+1:
    os.system("./initram-v5.sh -f file" + str(fileNum) + ".gro -o file" + str(fileNum) + "_aa.gro -to amber -p topol.top")
    fileNum += 1
```

Comment: Thanks, enjoyed helping :D

Answer (score 0):

.py:

```
import os
os.system("C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c myscript.bat")
```

myscipt.bat:

```
for i in $(seq 53); do echo ./initram-v5.sh -f "file${i}.gro" -o "file${i}_aa.gro" -to amber -p topol.top; done
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and suggestion :)